# Why does npm install fail with Assertion failed: (fd > STDERR_FILENO) using buildah?

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab-auto-devops

Hey I have a Dockerfile for a project that I want to build inside of a Gitlab ci/cd pipeline running on Kubernetes.
The Image is built inside a buildah container from quay.io, but while the project compiles locally, it does not for the pipeline:

```
STEP 4/7: RUN npm install yarn
node: ../deps/uv/src/unix/core.c:633: uv__close: Assertion `fd > STDERR_FILENO' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
subprocess exited with status 134
subprocess exited with status 134
error building at STEP "RUN npm install yarn": exit status 134
```

In fact even `npm --version` fails with the same error.

I tried to reproduce the environment locally with `podman run --privileged -v $(pwd):/image quay.io/containers/buildah  buildah build image` which worked.
But locally I am running with runc, while the pipeline is running with crio.
I could not figure out how to run a container with crio.

What could be the cause of this? Could this be a crio configuration thing?
I'd appreciate any help in figuring out, where to even start searching.

Thanks :)

Comment: i have same issue in tekton, trying to build docker image using podman, same error on `npm install -g npm`